# Cleaning the form of straddle planche

Tags: bodyweight-exercises, calisthenics, form

What are the best exercises to "clean" the form of the straddle planche?

I have seen that many people use the bent arm planche as a matter of proprioception of the body, other use bands and others use a human assistance. But I'm not really sure what method is the best to correct my specific mistakes.

My main mistakes are hips too high in the air and legs not hig enough (my body forms an inverted "V" , where the higher point is my hip).

Comment: This questions will lead to opinions, there really aren't enough calisthenic athletes to create true best practices through studies, so all we can really do is go off our own experiences. This question is also a bit hard to answer because it depends on why your hips are too high and your legs are not high enough. If the strength in your lower back/hips is lacking to pull your legs up, try tuck planche progressions. If shoulder/lat/straight arm strength is lacking, you can try lying straight arm flies. Those two things gave me the fastest progress when learning straddle/strict planche.

Comment: I would not recommend bent arm planche to fix your V form. I have never used bands, but in theory I would assume they are optimal since they allow you to keep the strict form while lightening the load. Lying straight arm flies are the upside down version of the planche and using bands will allow you to do the same thing rightside up. Whichever is more convenient is what I would use to add shoulder, lat, and straight arm strength.

Comment: First of all congratz for the full planche ! ATM I'm using a band that is decreasing 8 kg from my bodyweight placed on my pelvis, I can't say how is going with this exercise but the planche becomes considerably easier to manage. Unfortunately I don't have weights available to perform the flies anyway thanks for the another great tips @EricWarburton !

Comment: Thanks, I really can only hold full planche for a couple seconds so I still have a long ways to go.  Since your problem is your hips being too high, it might be good to start moving that band closer to your feet over time. That way you can slowly build up the strength required for perfect form.

Comment: never thinked about changing the position of the band! Thanks!